# Need for Performance in bash script

Tags: python, performance, bash, shell, scripting

I have 50000 files and each one has 10000 lines. Each line is in the form:

```
value_1 (TAB) value_2 (TAB) ... value_n
```

I wanted to remove specific values from every line in every file (i used cut to remove values 14-17) and write the results to a new file.

For doing that in one file, i wrote this code:

```
file=nameOfFile
newfile=$file".new"
i=0

while read line
do
    let i=i+1
    echo line: $i
    a=$i"p"
    lineFirstPart=$(sed -n -e $a $file | cut -f 1-13)
    #echo lineFirstPart: $lineFirstPart
    lineSecondPart=$(sed -n -e $a $file | cut -f 18-)
    #echo lineSecondPart: $lineSecondPart
    newline=$lineFirstPart$lineSecondPart
    echo $newline >> $newfile
done < $file
```

This takes ~45 secs for one file, which means for all it will take about: 45x50000 = 625h ~= 26 days!

Well, **i need something faster**, e.g. a solution that cats the whole file, applies the two cut commands simultaneusly or something like that i guess.

Also solutions in python are accepted + appreciated but bash scripting is preferable!

Comment: Isn't your script just doing `cut -f 1-13,18- $file > $newfile`? Am I missing something?

Comment: why you use `while..loop`? use only `sed` command on file to replace `""` instead of specific value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The entire `while` loop can be replaced with one line:

```
cut -f1-13,18- $file > $newfile
```